# Render Bokeh plots in Flask app hosted on Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, flask, bokeh

I have the following basic Bokeh plot served by Heroku at https://macabre-spirit-1593.herokuapp.com/1/.  When I run this app locally, or save the Heroku page and open it locally, the plot appears, but when I view the page on Heroku the plot is absent.  Why doesn't the plot appear when served from Heroku?

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-0.9.2.min.css" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-0.9.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    Bokeh.$(function() {
    var all_models = [{"id": "cf51209d-4dca-4a94-befe-ce3130209c78", "attributes": {"names": [], "tags": [], "renderers": [], "doc": null, "id": "cf51209d-4dca-4a94-befe-ce3130209c78", "callback": null}, "type": "DataRange1d"}, {"id": "9b2f5c69-f94b-46ea-bd71-7c5a39f83663", "attributes": {"tags": [], "x": {"field": "x"}, "doc": null, "fill_alpha": {"value": 0.1}, "line_alpha": {"value": 0.1}, "y": {"field": "y"}, "line_color": {"value": "#1f77b4"}, "id": "9b2f5c69-f94b-46ea-bd71-7c5a39f83663", "fill_color": {"value": "#1f77b4"}, "size": {"value": 10, "units": "screen"}}, "type": "Circle"}, {"id": "1d823a82-3c1c-4d66-b72b-23e04fd18201", "attributes": {"names": [], "tags": [], "renderers": [], "doc": null, "id": "1d823a82-3c1c-4d66-b72b-23e04fd18201", "callback": null}, "type": "DataRange1d"}, {"id": "560a370b-8b4a-4727-bf2e-86f01b41218a", "attributes": {"data_source": {"id": "8ee8c50b-f9b1-46cf-a1a5-5b0d3bac8180", "type": "ColumnDataSource"}, "selection_glyph": null, "doc": null, "tags": [], "id": "560a370b-8b4a-4727-bf2e-86f01b41218a", "nonselection_glyph": {"id": "9b2f5c69-f94b-46ea-bd71-7c5a39f83663", "type": "Circle"}, "glyph": {"id": "b73f3e41-5552-4ad4-98e0-5989ee44e3e9", "type": "Circle"}}, "type": "GlyphRenderer"}, {"id": "fc1bf45f-7f16-4de5-b36f-263f20192585", "attributes": {"doc": null, "tags": [], "num_minor_ticks": 5, "id": "fc1bf45f-7f16-4de5-b36f-263f20192585", "mantissas": [2, 5, 10]}, "type": "BasicTicker"}, {"subtype": "Figure", "id": "378da220-9181-4a82-a6e8-f49f0227e53a", "attributes": {"right": [], "renderers": [{"id": "d766cfd4-5a4e-4e0a-b7e6-f81ae955566f", "type": "LinearAxis"}, {"id": "60f36638-9ebd-4472-9cc6-d520bb388413", "type": "Grid"}, {"id": "31c32470-e492-4ca3-94c5-430c5c210c6f", "type": "LinearAxis"}, {"id": "8d162596-51c4-4220-bbb9-64612ae58d52", "type": "Grid"}, {"id": "560a370b-8b4a-4727-bf2e-86f01b41218a", "type": "GlyphRenderer"}], "tools": [{"id": "280dbfef-17cd-4da0-ae45-56c01634dd87", "type": "PanTool"}, {"id": "c498d4b6-f4b4-4ed7-96d3-6a056ec29f42", "type": "WheelZoomTool"}, {"id": "e217ba06-b6fc-4a3f-97df-c21ee05e5d6e", "type": "BoxZoomTool"}, {"id": "18cc3cc0-befb-437b-9fd8-c33023baba82", "type": "PreviewSaveTool"}, {"id": "dff98135-cbce-440e-a2ce-c25bb32e88c1", "type": "ResizeTool"}, {"id": "9c973e40-a37f-4573-9d6a-7c81c864656d", "type": "ResetTool"}, {"id": "162b7eef-2558-4934-8f68-783561eea3c0", "type": "HelpTool"}], "left": [{"id": "31c32470-e492-4ca3-94c5-430c5c210c6f", "type": "LinearAxis"}], "doc": null, "above": [], "tool_events": {"id": "76240f36-4b23-431a-941b-ed95c63865a8", "type": "ToolEvents"}, "tags": [], "id": "378da220-9181-4a82-a6e8-f49f0227e53a", "extra_y_ranges": {}, "y_range": {"id": "1d823a82-3c1c-4d66-b72b-23e04fd18201", "type": "DataRange1d"}, "extra_x_ranges": {}, "x_range": {"id": "cf51209d-4dca-4a94-befe-ce3130209c78", "type": "DataRange1d"}, "below": [{"id": "d766cfd4-5a4e-4e0a-b7e6-f81ae955566f", "type": "LinearAxis"}]}, "type": "Plot"}, {"id": "b73f3e41-5552-4ad4-98e0-5989ee44e3e9", "attributes": {"tags": [], "x": {"field": "x"}, "doc": null, "fill_alpha": {"value": 1.0}, "line_alpha": {"value": 1.0}, "y": {"field": "y"}, "line_color": {"value": "#1f77b4"}, "id": "b73f3e41-5552-4ad4-98e0-5989ee44e3e9", "fill_color": {"value": "#1f77b4"}, "size": {"value": 10, "units": "screen"}}, "type": "Circle"}, {"id": "9c95ae2d-01d0-4794-856b-3a5e3ef0f4d5", "attributes": {"doc": null, "tags": [], "num_minor_ticks": 5, "id": "9c95ae2d-01d0-4794-856b-3a5e3ef0f4d5", "mantissas": [2, 5, 10]}, "type": "BasicTicker"}, {"id": "e217ba06-b6fc-4a3f-97df-c21ee05e5d6e", "attributes": {"doc": null, "tags": [], "id": "e217ba06-b6fc-4a3f-97df-c21ee05e5d6e", "dimensions": ["width", "height"], "plot": {"subtype": "Figure", "id": "378da220-9181-4a82-a6e8-f49f0227e53a", "type": "Plot"}}, "type": "BoxZoomTool"}, {"id": "dff98135-cbce-440e-a2ce-c25bb32e88c1", "attributes": {"doc": null, "tags": [], "id": "dff98135-cbce-440e-a2ce-c25bb32e88c1", "plot": {"subtype": "Figure", "id": "378da220-9181-4a82-a6e8-f49f0227e53a", "type": "Plot"}}, "type": "ResizeTool"}, {"id": "31c32470-e492-4ca3-94c5-430c5c210c6f", "attributes": {"tags": [], "ticker": {"id": "9c95ae2d-01d0-4794-856b-3a5e3ef0f4d5", "type": "BasicTicker"}, "doc": null, "plot": {"subtype": "Figure", "id": "378da220-9181-4a82-a6e8-f49f0227e53a", "type": "Plot"}, "id": "31c32470-e492-4ca3-94c5-430c5c210c6f", "formatter": {"id": "21009128-6c70-460e-9e2b-5029ea73e81e", "type": "BasicTickFormatter"}}, "type": "LinearAxis"}, {"id": "ebb30075-6525-4eb8-91a6-1ad6ef5da992", "attributes": {"id": "ebb30075-6525-4eb8-91a6-1ad6ef5da992", "doc": null, "tags": []}, "type": "BasicTickFormatter"}, {"id": "8d162596-51c4-4220-bbb9-64612ae58d52", "attributes": {"tags": [], "ticker": {"id": "9c95ae2d-01d0-4794-856b-3a5e3ef0f4d5", "type": "BasicTicker"}, "doc": null, "plot": {"subtype": "Figure", "id": "378da220-9181-4a82-a6e8-f49f0227e53a", "type": "Plot"}, "id": "8d162596-51c4-4220-bbb9-64612ae58d52", "dimension": 1}, "type": "Grid"}, {"id": "d766cfd4-5a4e-4e0a-b7e6-f81ae955566f", "attributes": {"tags": [], "ticker": {"id": "fc1bf45f-7f16-4de5-b36f-263f20192585", "type": "BasicTicker"}, "doc": null, "plot": {"subtype": "Figure", "id": "378da220-9181-4a82-a6e8-f49f0227e53a", "type": "Plot"}, "id": "d766cfd4-5a4e-4e0a-b7e6-f81ae955566f", "formatter": {"id": "ebb30075-6525-4eb8-91a6-1ad6ef5da992", "type": "BasicTickFormatter"}}, "type": "LinearAxis"}, {"id": "8ee8c50b-f9b1-46cf-a1a5-5b0d3bac8180", "attributes": {"tags": [], "doc": null, "column_names": ["x", "y"], "id": "8ee8c50b-f9b1-46cf-a1a5-5b0d3bac8180", "data": {"x": [1, 2, 3], "y": [4, 5, 6]}, "selected": {"1d": {"indices": []}, "2d": {"indices": []}, "0d": {"indices": [], "flag": false}}, "callback": null}, "type": "ColumnDataSource"}, {"id": "21009128-6c70-460e-9e2b-5029ea73e81e", "attributes": {"id": "21009128-6c70-460e-9e2b-5029ea73e81e", "doc": null, "tags": []}, "type": "BasicTickFormatter"}, {"id": "9c973e40-a37f-4573-9d6a-7c81c864656d", "attributes": {"doc": null, "tags": [], "id": "9c973e40-a37f-4573-9d6a-7c81c864656d", "plot": {"subtype": "Figure", "id": "378da220-9181-4a82-a6e8-f49f0227e53a", "type": "Plot"}}, "type": "ResetTool"}, {"id": "280dbfef-17cd-4da0-ae45-56c01634dd87", "attributes": {"doc": null, "tags": [], "id": "280dbfef-17cd-4da0-ae45-56c01634dd87", "dimensions": ["width", "height"], "plot": {"subtype": "Figure", "id": "378da220-9181-4a82-a6e8-f49f0227e53a", "type": "Plot"}}, "type": "PanTool"}, {"id": "76240f36-4b23-431a-941b-ed95c63865a8", "attributes": {"doc": null, "tags": [], "geometries": [], "id": "76240f36-4b23-431a-941b-ed95c63865a8"}, "type": "ToolEvents"}, {"id": "18cc3cc0-befb-437b-9fd8-c33023baba82", "attributes": {"doc": null, "tags": [], "id": "18cc3cc0-befb-437b-9fd8-c33023baba82", "plot": {"subtype": "Figure", "id": "378da220-9181-4a82-a6e8-f49f0227e53a", "type": "Plot"}}, "type": "PreviewSaveTool"}, {"id": "162b7eef-2558-4934-8f68-783561eea3c0", "attributes": {"doc": null, "tags": [], "id": "162b7eef-2558-4934-8f68-783561eea3c0", "plot": {"subtype": "Figure", "id": "378da220-9181-4a82-a6e8-f49f0227e53a", "type": "Plot"}}, "type": "HelpTool"}, {"id": "c498d4b6-f4b4-4ed7-96d3-6a056ec29f42", "attributes": {"doc": null, "tags": [], "id": "c498d4b6-f4b4-4ed7-96d3-6a056ec29f42", "dimensions": ["width", "height"], "plot": {"subtype": "Figure", "id": "378da220-9181-4a82-a6e8-f49f0227e53a", "type": "Plot"}}, "type": "WheelZoomTool"}, {"id": "60f36638-9ebd-4472-9cc6-d520bb388413", "attributes": {"tags": [], "ticker": {"id": "fc1bf45f-7f16-4de5-b36f-263f20192585", "type": "BasicTicker"}, "doc": null, "plot": {"subtype": "Figure", "id": "378da220-9181-4a82-a6e8-f49f0227e53a", "type": "Plot"}, "id": "60f36638-9ebd-4472-9cc6-d520bb388413", "dimension": 0}, "type": "Grid"}];
    Bokeh.load_models(all_models);
    var plots = [{'elementid': '6368f3cb-5e73-48dd-8ba6-757b1c0a1826', 'modeltype': 'Plot', 'modelid': '378da220-9181-4a82-a6e8-f49f0227e53a'}];
    for (idx in plots) {
        var plot = plots[idx];
        var model = Bokeh.Collections(plot.modeltype).get(plot.modelid);
        Bokeh.logger.info('Realizing plot:')
        Bokeh.logger.info(' - modeltype: ' + plot.modeltype);
        Bokeh.logger.info(' - modelid: ' + plot.modelid);
        Bokeh.logger.info(' - elementid: ' + plot.elementid);
        var view = new model.default_view({
            model: model,
            el: '#' + plot.elementid
        });
        Bokeh.index[plot.modelid] = view;
    }
});
</script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class=page>
      <h1>Plot 2</h1>
      <div class="plotdiv" id="6368f3cb-5e73-48dd-8ba6-757b1c0a1826"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Heroku page is served over HTTPS.  The resources on the page are hard coded to be served over HTTP.  Modern browsers detect and block this for security reasons; you can dismiss the warning and observe that the plot appears.  Change the linked resources so they are served over HTTPS as well, or better yet omit the scheme and let the browser decide.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-0.9.2.min.css" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-0.9.2.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The Bokeh documentation available at http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/embed.html states the following:

> When embedding in a page served via HTTPS, any scripts and resources
>   must also be loaded via HTTPS or the browser will refuse to load due
>   to an “unsafe” script. For this situation, the Bokeh CDN resources are
>   also available via HTTPS, by replacing “http” with “https” in the
>   above URLs.

Since Heroku apps are served over HTTPS, the Bokeh stylesheet and script links should start with `https` instead of `http`.

```
<link href="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-0.12.6.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-widgets-0.12.6.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<script src="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-0.12.6.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-widgets-0.12.6.min.js"></script>
```